# Sumifs formula where sum range changes depending on Cell Value

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to do a SUMIFS formula where the column I am summing (the sum_range) will depend on the column heading matching a cell value in another sheet.

So for example, cell A2 in my sheet might say 'Actual Sales' and the formula will sum column X in my data sheet (because cell X1 = "Actual Sales").  But if I change cell A2 to 'Budgeted Sales' I want the formula to sum from column AG (so cell AG1 = "Budgeted Sales").

The other criteria in the SUMIFS formula will not change.

I managed to use an Index & Match formula when doing this on a SUMIF formula but it does not seem to work on the SUMIFS formula.

The basic formula would be as follows:

`=SUMIFS(DATA!X:X,DATA!F:F,B26,DATA!D:D,C10,DATA!E:E,DATA!C11)`

The formula above is summing column X (Actual Sales) but I want that range to be dependent on what I enter in a particular cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should go for pivot tables. try it

Answer (score 2):

You can just `INDIRECT` to specify a range dynamically based on a string input, such as `SUM(INDIRECT("DATA!D:D"))` which sums all values in column `D`. Combine this with an `IF` in order to switch the range used based on a certain condition. You can use this with any formula, including `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS`.

For example:
[image: INDIRECT Example]
In this example, there is a `SumColumn` that contains the number of the `SumColumn` that I wish to sum. Valid values are `1` and `2`.

`SumColumn1` and `SumColumn2` simply contain values (no formulas).

Cell `B2` contains the formula that uses `INDIRECT` with `SUMIFS` to sum values based on a condition (all values must be `>1`). The part that defines the range is:

```
INDIRECT(IF(DATA!$A$2=1,"DATA!C:C","DATA!D:D"))
```

Basically, if the data in cell `A2` is equal to `1`, then use a range of `DATA!C:C`; otherwise use `DATA!D:D`.

Now just wrap this in the regular `SUMIF` (or `SUMIFS`in your case) to get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this assuming for demonstration purposes data are in same sheet in columns A and B:-

```
=SUM(A2:B4*(A1:B1=$C$1))
```

entered as an array formula in C2.

[image]

If you had non-numeric cells in your range of data it wouldn't work, but you could try

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:B4),A2:B4,0)*(A1:B1=$C$1))
```

Here's another method that only selects the column you want (non-array formula)

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH($C$1,$A$1:$B$1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(4,MATCH($C$1,$A$1:$B$1,0))))
```

but you have to put the range of rows (in this case 2 & 4) that you want.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$1,$A$1:$B$1,0)),"$1","")&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($C$1,$A$1:$B$1,0)),"$1","")))
```

is better because it sums the whole column.

However the standard method is to use INDEX to return a whole column:-

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:B,,MATCH($C$1,$A1:$B1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also combine offset & match in your `sumifs` to get a dynamic array.  In your example it would look something like

```
=SUM(OFFSET(DATA!A:A,0,MATCH(A2,DATA!1:1,0)-1),DATA!F:F,B26,DATA!D:D,C10,DATA!E:E,DATA!C11)
```

Also consider limiting the number of cells looked at to be more memory efficient, i.e. instead of looking at entire `row 1`, maybe you look only in columns `A1:ZA1` so excel doesn't look through entire sheet and instead of looking at all rows in `column A` you look at rows `A1:A100000`, or something to that effect.